# Php - How do perform string conversion from HTML special char to UTF-8

Tags: php, string, escaping, special-characters

I need to perform conversion from a HTML special characters like "*& nbsp;*" to the corresponding in UTF-8 like " " (blank space) in a string.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: [**Yes Angelo, with this >>> function**](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: And I'm just wondering, is this because you already have `&nbsp;` in a page or do you wish to perform a "find and replace" for something that is contained in a data file? Had to ask, just in case that is what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I get from a table in my database a field that contains HTML content that has suffered probably an escape. I need to serve this string to a template and I need to convert HTML special characters.

html_entity_decode() return an error like "Invalid multibyte..."

Comment: @AngeloG. If you wish to find and replace/delete then you could use this snippet: `$text_description="&nbsp;"; $text_description = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text_description); echo $text_description;` **or** you could replace `('&nbsp;', ' ', $text_description)` with `('&nbsp;', '', $text_description)` having deleted `&nbsp;` altogether.

Comment: @AngeloG. ^-- if that's what you meant/need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function :

```
html_entity_decode()
```

html_entity_decode — Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters
(include UTF-8)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php